# select countMerge from ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree materialized_view

Tags: clickhouse, materialized-views

Recently I started using clickhouse and I have some troubles.
I use cluster with 3 shards and each shard has an extra replication, thus there are 6 servers in total.

I create local MV on local table containing complete data (called it tbl), and create distributed MV based on local MV.
Local table containing complete data, or tbl uses ReplicatedMergeTree as engine. Local MV uses ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree as engine.
In addition, I recreated every MVs on test database with POPULATE. In this way, there is no possible of duplicated insertion.

The problem is that,
when I select countMerge from distributed MV, I got twice the correct answer (i,e., if the correct answer is 50, I got 100.),
while select uniqExactMerge from distributed MV will give a correct result.

Here is my script:

local MV script:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test ON CLUSTER cc_cluster;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS
test.user_event_stat_scene_mv_local_test_v2 ON CLUSTER cc_cluster
ENGINE = ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{layer}-{shard}/test.user_event_stat_scene_mv_local_test_v2', '{replica}')
PARTITION BY (dt)
ORDER BY (dt, scene)
POPULATE
AS select
    countState(1) as expos,
    countState(if(click>0, 1, null)) as clicks,
    sumState(if(click=1, watch, 0)) as dr,
    countState(if(click=1 and tbl.cost_cnt>0, 1, null)) as cost_cnt,
    sumState(if(click=1, tbl.cost_total, 0)) as cost_total,
    countState(if(click=1 and tbl.chat_cnt>0, 1, null)) as chat_cnt,
    uniqExactState(recom_token) as item_expos,
    uniqExactState(if(click=1, recom_token, null)) as item_clicks,
    uniqExactState(uid) as user_expos,
    uniqExactState(if(click=1, uid, null)) as user_clicks,
    uniqExactState(if(click=1 and tbl.cost_cnt>0, uid, null)) as user_costs,
    uniqExactState(if(click=1 and tbl.chat_cnt>0, uid, null)) as user_chats,
    scene,
    toFixedString(dt, 8) as dt
FROM recom_stats_dws.user_event_log_day_local as tbl
GROUP BY dt, scene;
```

distributed MV script is below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
test.user_event_stat_scene_mv_all_test_v2
ON CLUSTER cc_cluster
AS test.user_event_stat_scene_mv_local_test_v2
ENGINE = Distributed(cc_cluster, test, user_event_stat_scene_mv_local_test_v2, rand());
```

query script is :

```
select
    countMerge(expos) as expos,
    countMerge(clicks) as clicks,
    sumMerge(dr) as dr,
    countMerge(cost_cnt) as cost_cnt,
    sumMerge(cost_total) as cost_total,
    countMerge(chat_cnt) as chat_cnt, 
    uniqExactMerge(item_expos) as item_expos, 
    uniqExactMerge(item_clicks) as item_clicks, 
    uniqExactMerge(user_expos) as user_expos,
    uniqExactMerge(user_clicks) as user_clicks,
    uniqExactMerge(user_costs) as user_costs,
    uniqExactMerge(user_chats) as user_chats,
    scene,
    dt
FROM test.user_event_stat_scene_mv_all_test_v2 as tbl
GROUP BY dt, scene
order by dt, scene;
```

PS:

- local MV = test.user_event_stat_scene_mv_local_test_v2
- distributed MV = test.user_event_stat_scene_mv_all_test_v2
- local table containing complete data = recom_stats_dws.user_event_log_day_local

Which part may I did something wrong?
hope to get your help XD

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/16208

You have executed POPULATE twice. At each replica. It doubled the data.

You need to run POPULATE only at one replica.